# convert "-1" string to integer using python getting error massege - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm trying to convert a string from feature class layer that contain '-1' to integer using `if int(Floor)==-1:` and get this -

[image: error message]

Thanks

Comment: Can you expand? What string are you trying to convert?

Comment: You aren't converting `'-1'`, you're converting `'-'`.

Comment: why ? and how can i fix it ? thanks

Comment: You haven't provided information to determine that. Give a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code and input data.

Answer (score 1):

You're running Windows. That probably means that UTF-16LE got mixed up in there somewhere.

```
>>> int('-\x001\x00')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'


>>> int('-\x001\x00'.decode('utf-16le'))
-1
```

Comment: now i get this : Floor=int(Floor.decode('utf-16le'))
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x31 in position 0: truncated data

Comment: Print out the repr of the data you're getting.